# JAX-WS returns null pointer exception

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, soap, jax-ws

I wrote a JAX-WS web service for my project.I host the site in the server and when i call the web service via soapUI tool it returns the null pointer exception when run the method...

This is my error on the console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at lk.slsi.webService.webServiceforCustoms.getXmlbyDate(webServiceforCustoms.java:28) ~[classes/:slsi-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81) [jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

This is my Web Service class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lk.slsi.webService;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import lk.slsi.services.permitServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@WebService(serviceName = "customsPermit",name = "permitRelease",portName = "nswPort",targetNamespace = "https://nationalsinglewindow.gov.lk/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class webServiceforCustoms {

    @Autowired
    private permitServices permitServices;


    @WebMethod
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyDate(@WebParam(name = "123") String dtIssue) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByDate(dtIssue);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public CustomsPermit getXmlbyEntryNo(String SNumber) {
        CustomsPermit permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitBySNumber(SNumber);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyVATNo(String importerVAT) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByImporterVAT(importerVAT);
        return permitRelease;
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>


        <!--Add mysql dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>         
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I assume this null pointer exception will be accrue when using the **@autowire** dependency... Am i need to implement special dependency for build a relationship between jax-ws annotations and spring mvc...

Please give me a solution...

Comment: how/where are you defining the service? Also instructor injection would fail faster if it is missing and give better error detail.

Comment: I added autowire for base path... so other methods use this tequniqe... It works fine

Comment: ?? Where is the service getting created? ARe you defining it as a `Bean` in a configuration or a `Component`, `service` et.c and component scanning it? Autowiring is for injecting dependencies *not* creating them.

Comment: I call this method for other classes...

Comment: You're not understanding what I am asking. The `permitServices` needs to be created and managed by Spring to be eligable for Autowiring. Thus it needs to be created in `Configuration` class and annotated with `Bean` or `Component`, `Service` needs to be placed on it for it to be picked up by the `ComponentScan`. Please refer to Spring documentation if you have not already done so.

Comment: @ Darren Forsythe I use by component scan

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `ComponentScan` is scanning the package the `permitServices` is in. It would be helpful if you could provide the configuration(s) doing the scanning and the `permitService` class.

Comment: yes sir...all works fine.. I think the error is in @Autowired annotation.. I think autowired not working for JAX-WS.... JAX-RS also have the same problem.. I use a special dependency for rest..Then it works fine ...But JAX_WS not works that dependency.